# RMAN archivelog backup in Oracle 11gR2

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, backup, rman

I use below command to do RMAN backups on `rhel 5.9`,  but archivelog backups always ends up in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`

```
Backup as compressed backupset database plus archivelog format '/path'
```

How to use the same path as mentioned in the above command to get both backupset of database in same location or other desirable location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the format string twice, once for database backupsets, and once for the archivelog backups, for example:

```
backup as compressed backupset database format '/path/%U' plus archivelog format '/path/%U';
```

Comment: I will try and comment the result